# Avrdude with Pi3B problem with dependencies

Tags: hardware

I've installed the newest version OS, but now I have to fix connection with my additional components. I have to install avrdude_5.10-4_armhf.deb. I always used this [tutorial](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/gertboard/arduino-ide-installation-isp/).
However when I try install avrdude I got:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of avrdude:armhf:
 avrdude:armhf depends on libncurses5 (>= 5.5-5~).
 avrdude:armhf depends on libreadline6 (>= 6.0).
 avrdude:armhf depends on libtinfo5.
 avrdude:armhf depends on libusb-0.1-4 (>= 2:0.1.12).
```

I installed libncurses5, libusb-0.1-4 can not find libreadline6. However it looks like the installed dependecies are too hight? Anyone tried install it on Bullseye?

Answer (score 0):

Install the supported version (7.1) from the repository.